# R web scraping using Rvest: incompatible sizes error

Tags: r, rvest

**Rstudio** version Version 1.0.143 and using **Rvest** package.

I am trying to scrape data from a webpage but I get an error:

```
Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : incompatible sizes (20 != 9)
```

I believe its due to some variables have no data therefore its number of rows are shorter than others. Could you please validate that this assumption is correct and how to rectify it. Is there a way to write NA for no data for that row so that all variables have equal row numbers.

Below are my codes.

```
domain_web <- ("https://www.domain.com.au/sold-listings/?area=blue-mountains-surrounds-nsw,canterbury-bankstown-nsw,eastern-suburbs-nsw,hawkesbury-nsw,hills-nsw,inner-west-nsw,liverpool-fairfield-nsw,macarthur-camden-nsw,northern-beaches-nsw,northern-suburbs-nsw,north-shore-lower-nsw,north-shore-upper-nsw,parramatta-nsw,st-george-nsw,sutherland-nsw,sydney-city-nsw,western-sydney-nsw&sort=suburb-asc&page=%d")


map_df(1:50, function(i) {
  cat(".")

  pg <- read_html(sprintf(domain_web, i))

  list(Date = html_text(html_nodes(pg, ".is-sold")),
             Price = html_text(html_nodes(pg, ".listing-result__price")),
             Address = html_text(html_nodes(pg, ".listing-result__address-line-1 span")),
             Suburb = html_text(html_nodes(pg, ".listing-result__address-line-2 span")),
             Bedroom = html_text(html_nodes(pg, ".listing-result__feature-bed")),
             Bathroom = html_text(html_nodes(pg, ".listing-result__feature-bathroom")),
             Garage = html_text(html_nodes(pg, ".listing-result__feature-parking")), stringsAsFactors = F)}) ->Property_price
```

I have run above command individually for Date and Price - it works but I receive error code mentioned above when rest of the variables are included.

Really really appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: How about inserting `ifelse` statement while creating your list? Something like `ifelse(is.null(html_text(html_nodes(pg, ".is-sold"))), NA, html_text(html_nodes(pg, ".is-sold")))`

Comment: Their condition of use prohibits: "(e) use any robot, spider, or other device or process to retrieve, index, or in any way reproduce, modify or circumvent the navigational structure, security or presentation of the Fairfax Network;" If this is just a randomly chosed website, then you should find one that does not make it a criminal offense to "scrape" its data.

Comment: Never thought along that line. Appreciate for bringing this up.